# SOLVED- Black screen when booting up raspberry pi

Tags: boot, ubuntu, screen, failure

I use a 4GB raspberry pi 4B. Recently, I switched to Ubuntu, and it had been working fine, until one day, I booted it up and the screen was black. Sometimes a glitched Ubuntu loading screen appears before a black screen, only containing a blinking text cursor which I can’t interact with. I’ve tried using terminals with alt + f(n), but, for some reason, I can’t write out files that allow to resolve the issue. I’ve tried modifying some lines in the config.txt file, like hdmi_safe, hdmi_force_hotplug and hdmi_force_output, but nothing works. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Just restore from your backup.

Comment: If you can see a cursor, then it's unlikely a HDMI config change will fix anything, since HDMI is not broken. did you try `Ctrl+Alt+f(n)` instead of just `Alt+f(n)` as for `until one day` ... what happened the previous day? probably some Ubuntu update?

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+f(n) seems to do the same thing. However, when I did that after holding the up and down arrows while it loaded, the Ubuntu loading screen appeared. Then, an error popped up saying “[FAILED] Failed to start snapd.failure.service - Failure handling of the snapd snap”. As for the day before, I had been running some terminal commands, specifically opencv build, and changing some Geany settings. I don’t know whether it got updated, but I reckon I just unplugged it.

Comment: this site is not a forum ... please add all information to the question ... do not use comments

Comment: The question doesn't seem to be editable, and I didn't believe that what I'd done before would be so important, since many people reported having this problem right after Ubuntu updates.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the problem. Given that I was unable to rewrite files, I started by doing `sudo mount -o remount,rw /`. Then, I did `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` and `sudo service gdm3 restart`. Immediately after that, my desktop appeared. However, now I have to do this every time I want to boot up my Raspberry Pi, so if anyone knows how to solve the rest, that would be helpful.

Comment: I was trying to make an autostart file and when I rebooted,  a black screen with the mouse cursor. I tried many different keyboard with no results. When I right clicked with the mouse, several options appeared, one was a terminal, which I used to correct the autostart file.